# Home media storage solution

Tags: storage, hardware-rec

I record lots of personal HD film footage and am looking for a cheap way to store all of this. I take ~120 GB of footage each month, so something expandable would be nice... something that might be able to hold 6+ SATA drives.

There is a low load requirement, as there is never more than a user or two... but it should be able to keep up with streaming 2 simultanious HD videos.

I don't really want to spend more than $200-$300 on top of the $900 I am thinking of spending for 6X2TB SATA drives@ $150 apiece, but I am willing to pay extra for a quality solution.

Should I get a cheap NAS server? a cheap multi-drive external enclosure? should I just get some used systems off craigslist? If it is an independent system I'll probably just throw ubuntu on it since I can maintain that well.  Its easy to do a software raid from ubuntu too, if I choose to go that way.

Thanks

Comment: Don't forget to contemplate disk mirroring requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a new computer. Your budget is too low for specialized hardware which is often overpriced because of its "speciality" and all it does is being computer with few features.

Answer (score 7):

Buy a [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/products/index.php). It's cheaper than a new computer (of any decent quality), smaller, quieter, and does a better job of storing an expanding dataset reliably (single-drive failures are no problem).

You can expand them without losing any data, and even while the volume is still online and being accessed (it just slows down a bit during the upsizing).

I've owned one for quite some time now, and [they're the shiznit](http://www.drobo.com/resources/beyondraid.php).

Zero maintenance, just replace drives if and as they fail over time. No patching, no vulnerabilities, no headaches. It does what it does better than any computer can, and you can start out with smaller drives now and replace them as you need to grow, keeping your cash outlay smaller up front.

---

Update re building a base-level PC and doing the RAID yourself: By the time you buy all the parts to make a machine of decent reliability (you *do* care about your data, right?), how much will you have spent? How much is your time worth to mess around with the hardware and with Linux to get everything set up and configured -- plus the hassle to keep Linux patched as time goes on?

The base-model Drobo (four drive bays, USB 2.0, FireWire 800) is $399:

http://www.drobostore.com/store/drobo/en_US/buy/productID.111373000

You can even buy them preloaded with drives, which may or may not make sense for your application.

That's not much of a premium over rolling your own, and you won't get the sort of in-place upsizing the Drobo offers. There's even a $50 mail-in rebate until the end of March, making it $349.

http://www.drobo.com/mir/DroboRebate-US.pdf

Comment: Drobo's are awesome, but you are paying for a lot of their integration and design.  I would say if you are comfortable installing Ubuntu or other linux distribution you should look at rolling your own solution.  It will be significantly cheaper.  There a number of high quality linux distributions geared towards use on these sorts of NAS that include browser accessible configuration pages to manager storage, permissions, users, etc.

Comment: @user26453: I updated my answer to respond to your suggestion. What you suggest really doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking into Windows Home Server, I think they has great expandability but it isn't free like ubuntu. I think its $99 but you can expand raids and drive sizes by just adding new hard drives into the mix.

Comment: You can also set up automatic Backups from your other windows machines. I have not used it but i have heard of its simplicity.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am mostly looking for hardware help.  Ubuntu can actually expand raids as well.

Comment: Windows Home Server does not support RAID

Comment: You can use hardware raid, the windows has a raid-like feature, as far as software.

Comment: You can use hardware RAId, but that's not what your answer says. Your answer says use WHS because it's easy to expand RAID volumes, which is wrong. WHS has share duplication which makes a second copy of the data to a different hard drive. If gives you the redundancy of RAID 1 without the read-performance gain.

Comment: @MarkM, WHS also duplicates only the data you choose, so you're not mirroring 4GB swap files.

Comment: @hyperslug - I'm not arguing share duplication, I already listed that. I'm arguing the wrong statement from jburke about the ability to grow RAID volumes on the fly as a feature of WHS

Answer (score 1):

if its storage only, freenas might be worth looking at os wise. Hardwarewise, a decent desktop board these days has 6 sata ports + 1-2 ide- you could get away with a budget processor (even maybe something celery based).I wouldn't suggest getting used hardware - its gonna be a pain if something drops dead- other than the case. older cases are better made ;p

Comment: Many recommendations through superuser for FreeNAS.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I get a cheap NAS server?

Yes, however your budget is *extremely* difficult to work with. For the amount your looking for, you'll *barely* get a 2-drive NAS. *Maybe* 4 drive NASes are available if you look hard enough, but I doubt the quality in that price range.

> I don't really want to spend more than
>   $200-$300 on top of the $900 I am
>   thinking of spending for 6X2GB SATA
>   drives@ $150 apiece, but I am willing
>   to pay extra for a quality solution.

As far as I know.. there's no real vendor that sells a 6-bay solution for $300. There are *real quality* solutions out there, but way above and beyond that $200-300 range. 6-8 bay solutions teeter from $800-$1600 depending on features, vendors and included disks.

> a cheap multi-drive external
>   enclosure?

This is possible with eSATA enclosures. I've never personally used them so I can't recommend one. Someone recommended Drobo and while they are pretty sweet and versatile (low end models), my complaint with their 4-disk model is that it doesn't include 100/1000 ethernet (to my knowledge). Redundancy is great, but speed does become an issue with data storage (especially HD stuff) so unless you have firewire, I'd say Drobo isn't worth it without some access speed like gigabit or USB 3.0.

> should I just get some used systems
>   off craigslist?

No. Don't bother. Cheap is cheap and I wouldn't chance spending $200-$300 on something that may break down without a warranty, receipt or anything of substance.

> If it is an independent system I'll
>   probably just throw ubuntu on it since
>   I can maintain that well. Its easy to
>   do a software raid from ubuntu too, if
>   I choose to go that way.

If you have a big enough case (something with at least 3 5.25" external bays) you might want to look into a disk enclosure like [Supermicro's CSE-M35T-1B](http://www.newegg.com/product/product.aspx?item=n82e16817121405) (black version; there's an off white one available too). It houses 5 SATA disks and add a *good* RAID card, you have your own little NAS-ish storage. Granted, this enclosure is meant for one of Supermicro's Workstation/Server chassis, for the price ranging from $95-$150 (depending on vendors) it's a nice workaround (assuming you have a computer for it). I bought one on eBay and with the bing discount, I managed to get one for just around $88. I'm still setting it up so I can't say how good/bad it is, but it might just be the workaround you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to reiterate the Drobo answer - I say it doesn't get any easier for the flexibility it offers.

Also, they are much cheaper than $399 on Amazon now.  You're looking at $329.99 base price, with a $50 rebate after that - so [$279.99 total @ Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001CZ9ZEE).  I don't know whether to be happy about the price, or worried that a new model is on the way ;)